# Which Day of Christmas is it?

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, number-theory

## Preface

In the well known carol, [The Twelve Days of Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song)), the narrator is presented with several gifts each day. The song is *cumulative* - in each verse, a new gift is added, with a quantity one higher than the gift before it. One Partridge, Two Turtle Doves, Three French Hens, and so on.

At any given verse, **N**, we can calculate the cumulative sum of presents so far in the song by finding the **N**th [tetrahedral number](http://oeis.org/A000292), which gives the results:

```
Verse 1: 1
Verse 2: 4
Verse 3: 10
Verse 4: 20
Verse 5: 35
Verse 6: 56
Verse 7: 84
Verse 8: 120
Verse 9: 165
Verse 10: 220
Verse 11: 286
Verse 12: 364
```

For example, after verse 4, we've had **4*(1 partridge)**, **3*(2 turtle doves)**, **2*(3 French hens)** and **1*(4 calling birds)**. By summing these, we get `4(1) + 3(2) + 2(3) + 1(4) = 20`.

## The Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a positive integer representing the number of presents **364 ≥ p ≥ 1**, determines which day (verse) of Christmas it is.

For example, if **p = 286**, we are on the 11th day of Christmas. However, if **p = 287**, then the next load of presents has begun, meaning it is the 12th day.

Mathematically, this is finding the next tetrahedral number, and returning its position in the whole sequence of tetrahedral numbers.

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) wins.
- Standard golfing loopholes apply.
- When it comes to days, your program must be 1-indexed.
- Your submission must be a full program or a function - but not a snippet.

## Test Cases

```
1   ->  1
5   ->  3
75  ->  7
100 ->  8
220 ->  10
221 ->  11
364 ->  12
```

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, the *n'th* tetrahedral number is also the sum of the first *n* triangular numbers.

Comment: This might help: `x=>{while(x>p)p+=r+=++i;return i}`, I'm sure it can be made shorter in a language like JavaScript.

Comment: This is the earliest Christmas challenge ever, right? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Dennis (use vectorised minimum, `«`, and first index, `i`)

```
R+\⁺«i
```

**[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x@kHfOocdeh1Zn/j@453P6oaY37///RhjqmOuamOoYGBjpGRiBsqGNsZhILAA)**

#### How?

Not all that efficient - calculates the 1st through to nth tetrahedral numbers in order in a list and returns the 1-based index of the first that is equal to or greater.

```
R+\⁺«i - main link: n
R      - range                          [1,2,3,4,...,n]
 +\    - cumulative reduce by addition  [1,3,6,10,...,sum([1,2,3,4,...n])] i.e. triangle numbers
   ⁺   - duplicate previous link - another cumulative reduce by addition
                                        [1,4,10,20,...,nth tetrahedral]
    «  - min(that, n)                   [1,4,10,20,...,n,n,n]
     i - first index of n (e.g. if n=12:[1,4,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12] -> 4)
```

---

Previous 7 byters using lowered range `[0,1,2,3,...,n-1]` and counting tetrahedrals less than n:
`Ḷ+\⁺<µS`,
`Ḷ+\⁺<ḅ1`,
`Ḷ+\⁺<ċ1`, and
`Ḷ+\⁺<¹S`

Answer (score 19):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:int((n*6)**.33359)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Tc29DoIwEADg2T7F6URrNdZajI3dfAQ3dajQkiZymMIAi6@OoME4XC73911hrv3DlvfcAuqATZIgSyljaymlOtDem2nKgxE6MCZX4TjsWMxXL58M7aWghDzjcAyLU/DeRYeZAx@rEqKbyqzKnV4QX0VACAjRYuESwWWqqAYya82AUTLrTPHJwUM7N53@wshb3v2@nF3dQGZrV/@LF8EV3ysuNhu@HWM76rubhskY5f4N)

A direct formula with some curve-fitting, same as [the original one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108394/20260) found by Level River St.

The shifted equation `i**3-i==n*6` is close to `i**3==n*6` for large `i`. It solves to `i=(n*6)**(1/3)`. Taking the floor the rounds down as needed, compensating for the off-by-one.

But, there are 6 inputs on boundaries where the error takes it below an integer it should be above. All of these can be fixed by slightly increasing the exponent without introducing further errors.

---

### [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i**3-i<n*6and-~f(n,i+1)
```

The formula `n=i*(i+1)*(i+2)/6` for tetrahedral numbers can be more nicely written in `i+1` as `n*6=(i+1)**3-(i+1)`. So, we find the lowest `i` for which `i**3-i<n*6`. Each time we increment `i` starting from 1, the recursive calls adds `1` to the output. Starting from `i=1` rather than `i=0` compensates for the shift.

Comment: Nice. I thought about golfing mine this way, but I didn't do it. Nevertheless, I'll try shifting; our answers will still be different.

Comment: Woah. Your new one is amazing.

Comment: The 26-byte version fails for 364, which is excluded from the test range. `**.33359` works for one extra byte.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. Python exclusive ranges strike again!

Comment: `lambda n:n**.3336//.5501` saves a few bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Nice, I forgot about floor-dividing. Is there a chance the parameters could be mutually optimized to be shorter?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but multiplying instead of using 'and' (for the second thing) might be shorter.

Comment: @xnor Indeed. `lambda n:n**.3335//.55` works, saving two more bytes.

Comment: @J843136028 The `and` is for logical short-circuiting in order to terminate. All recursive definitions need something that can avoid evaluating the recursive call at some point.

Comment: @Dennis You should post it!

Comment: Alright, done. :)

Answer (score 10):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
2>.@-~3!inv]
```

There might be a golfier way to do this, but this is a lovely opportunity to use J's built-in function inversion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYGSn56BbZ6yYmVcW@z81OSNfIU0hNTE5Q8FQwVTB3FTB0MBAwcgIhA0VjM1M/gMA)

#### How it works

```
2>.@-~3!inv]  Monadic verb. Argument: n

           ]  Right argument; yield n.
      3       Yield 3.
       !inv   Apply the inverse of the ! verb to n and 3. This yields a real number.
              x!y computes Π(y)/(Π(y-x)Π(x)), where Π is the extnsion of the 
              factorial function to the real numbers. When x and y are non-negative
              integers, this equals yCx, the x-combinations of a set of order y.
 >.@-~        Combine the ceil verb (>.) atop (@) the subtraction verb (-) with
              swapped arguments (~).
2             Call it the combined verbs on the previous result and 2.
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda n:n**.3335//.55
```

Heavily inspired by [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108400/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#TY3BDoIwEETP8BVzIZRaQKjFhIhHv8JLDa0ScDUF4@dj6cnDbnayM28sOlzXST9vvQa1xHkhpVRlWSi19sbiwihr42j0viqOvo9hMhg5l8gx4oQG3Mf8uQt/Z5aPIy9zr2L7ciAMBKfpblglIBu10fQ8G7fAeja6LnT8uTejEjj6qfZ7gboOK8QPW/ztBlpYmsge@RlJ3adIwEgEYJatPw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
R‘c3<¹S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/0qGFGsrHNoZ3B/4/uOdz@qGmN@///hjoKpjoK5kBsaGCgo2BkBCaAosZmJgA)

#### How it works

```
R‘c3<¹S  Main link. Argument: n

R        Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 ‘       Increment; yield [2, ..., n+1].
  c3     Combinations; yield [C(2,3), ..., C(n+1,3)].
    <¹   Yield [C(2,3) < n, ..., C(n+1,3) < n].
      S  Sum; count the non-negative values of k for which C(k+2,3) < n.
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder, what can Jelly _not_ do?

Comment: One of these days someone is going to be like "Code Golf a fully featured MMO" and Dennis is going to post "Jelly, 29 bytes" or something stupid like that.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```js
n=>(F=k=>k<n?F(k+3*k/i++):i)(i=1)
```

Based on the recursive formula:

```
a(1) = 1
a(i) = (i + 3) * a(i - 1) / i
```

The second expression can also be written as ...

```
a(i) = a(i - 1) + 3 * a(i - 1) / i
```

... which is the one that we are using here.

`a(i - 1)` is actually stored in the `k` variable and passed to the next iteration until `k >= n`.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>(F=k=>k<n?F(k+3*k/i++):i)(i=1)

console.log(f(1));   // ->  1
console.log(f(5));   // ->  3
console.log(f(75));  // ->  7
console.log(f(100)); // ->  8
console.log(f(220)); // ->  10
console.log(f(221)); // ->  11
console.log(f(364)); // ->  12
```

Comment: This is sneakily short! Good job.

Comment: @FlipTack My first attempt was based on the formula you used. I had to change my plans. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

Edit: alternate version, still 26 bytes

```
->n{(n**0.3333*1.82).to_i}
```

Original version

```
->n{((n*6)**0.33355).to_i}
```

Uses the fact that `T(x) = x(x+1)(x+2)/6 = ((x+1)**3-(x+1))/6` which is very close to `(x+1)**3/6`.

The function simply multiplies by 6, finds a slightly tweaked version of the cube root (yes 5 decimal places are required) and returns the result truncated to an integer.

**Test program and output**

```
f=->n{((n*6)**0.33355).to_i}
[1,4,10,20,35,56,84,120,165,220,286,364].map{|i|p [i,f[i],f[i+1]]}

[1, 1, 2]
[4, 2, 3]
[10, 3, 4]
[20, 4, 5]
[35, 5, 6]
[56, 6, 7]
[84, 7, 8]
[120, 8, 9]
[165, 9, 10]
[220, 10, 11]
[286, 11, 12]
[364, 12, 13]
```

Comment: `0.3336` seems to work for the original version. (Edit: Never mind, Dennis points out I was forgetting about 364.)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Luke (making the function curried)*

```js
n=>f=i=>n<=i/6*-~i*(i+2)?i:f(-~i)
```

This is an unnamed lambda function which can be assigned to `func` and called with `func(220)()`, as described in [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11317/60919). My original, non-curried function looks like this:

```js
f=(n,i)=>n<=-~i*i/6*(i+2)?i:f(n,-~i)
```

This answer uses the fact that **x**th tetrahedral number can be found with the following function:

\$f(x) = \frac{x}6(x+1)(x+2)\$

The function works by recursively increasing `i`, and finding `tetrahedral(i)`, until it's larger than or equal to `n` (the number of presents given).

When called with one argument as expected, `i = undefined`, and therefore is not larger than `n`. This means `f(n,-~i)` is executed, and `-~undefined` evaluates to `1`, which sets off the recursion.

---

### Test Snippet:

```js
func = n=>f=i=>n<=i/6*-~i*(i+2)?i:f(-~i)

var tests = [1, 5, 75, 100, 220, 221, 364];
tests.forEach(n => console.log(n + ' => ' + func(n)()));
```

Comment: I was about to post the exact same answer. Beat me by 2 mins. Good job!

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by currying: `n=>g=i=>n<=i/6*++i*++i?i-2:g(~-i)`. You'd call it like `f(2)()`.

Comment: @Luke good spot, my curried function wasn't so short. Are you sure you don't want to post that as your own answer?

Comment: Nah, I'd do it if we were using a different formula, but now our solutions are nearly identical. I'd rather help you get on the same level as Arnauld. ;-)

Comment: `i=>n<=i` Beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
`G@H+IXn>}@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5/g7uCh7RmRZ1fr8P@/oYEBAA)

#### Explanation

```
`       % Do...while
  G     %   Push input, n
  @     %   Push iteration index (1-based), say m
  H     %   Push 2
  +     %   Add
  I     %   Push 3
  Xn    %   Binomial coefficient with inputs m+2, 3
  >     %   Is n greater than the binomial coefficient? If so: next iteration
}       %   Finally (execute after last iteration, before exiting the loop)
  @     %   Push last iteration index. This is the desired result
        % End (implicit)
        % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
XµNÌ3c¹‹_½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9xaKvf4R7j5EM7HzXsjD@09/9/IyNDAA)

**Explanation**

```
Xµ          # loop until counter equals 1
  NÌ3c      # binomial_coefficient(iteration_index+2,3)
      ¹     # push input
       ‹_   # not less than
         ½  # if true, increment counter
            # output last iteration index
```

Comment: Wow, binom is much smarter than `[N2Ý+P6÷¹Q#N>`, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 11 bytes

```
#3RL+B6f)lt
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%233RL%2BB6f%29lt&input=1)

```
#3RL+B6f)   -  while rtn <= input as i:
 3RL+       -     i+j for j in range(3)
     B      -    product(^)
      6f    -   ^/6
         lt - len(^)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
1n@*6§X³-X}a
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=MW5AKjanWLMtWH1h&input=MjIx) or [Verify all test cases at once](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=Tm1VezFuQCo2p1izLVh9YX0gcVI=&input=MQo1Cjc1CjEwMAoyMjAKMjIxCjM2NA==)

#### How it works

```
1n@*6§X³-X}a  // Implicit: U = input integer
  @       }a  // Find the smallest non-negative integer X which satisfies this condition:
      X³-X    //   (X ^ 3) - X
     §        //   is greater than or equal to
   *6         //   U * 6.
1n            // Subtract 1 from the result.
              // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

This is a simplification of the tetrahedral formula several other answers are using:

```
f(x) = (x)(x + 1)(x + 2)/6
```

By substituting `x - 1` for `x`, we can simplify this considerably:

```
f(x) = (x - 1)(x)(x + 1) / 6
f(x) = (x - 1)(x + 1)(x) / 6
f(x) = (x^2 - 1)(x) / 6
f(x) = (x^3 - x) / 6
```

Therefore, the correct result is one less than the smallest integer `x` such that `(x^3 - x) / 6` is greater than or equal to the input.

13-byte solution, inspired by @xnor's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108400/61613):

```
p.3335 /.55 f
```

A few more solutions @ETHproductions and I played around with

```
J+@*6§X³-X}a 
@*6§X³-X}a -1
@§X/6*°X*°X}a 
_³-V /6¨U}a -1
§(°V nV³ /6?´V:ß
§(°VV³-V /6?´V:ß
```

Test it [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=QKdYLzYqsFgqsFh9YQ==&input=MzY0).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
(0//.i_/;i+6#>i^3:>i+1)-1&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonnegative integer argument and returning a nonnegative integer (yeah, it works for day `0` too). We want to find the smallest integer `i` for which the input `#` is at most `i(i+1)(i+2)/6`, which is the formula for the number of gifts given on the first `i` days. Through mild algebraic trickery, the inequality `# ≤ i(i+1)(i+2)/6` is equivalent to `(i+1) + 6# ≤ (i+1)^3`. So the structure `0//.i_/;i+6#>i^3:>i+1` starts with a `0` and keeps adding `1` as long as the test `i+6#>i^3` is satisfied; then `(...)-1&` subtracts `1` at the end (rather than spend bytes with parentheses inside the inequality).

If we let the 12 Days of Christmas continue, we can handle about 65536 days before the built-in recursion limit for `//.` halts the process ... that's about 4.7 * 10^13 days, or about ten times the age of the universe thus far....

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
I.~3!2+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGul4KlXZ6xopJ2px8WVmpyRr6Cho5emZKCpYKhgqmBuqmBoYKBgZATChgrGZib//wMA)

This is more inefficient than using the inverse of factorial but happens to be shorter.

For example, if the input integer is *n* = 5, make the range `[2, n+1]`.

```
2 3 4 5 6 choose 3
0 1 4 10 20
```

These are the first 5 tetrahedral numbers. The next step is to determine which interval (day) *n* belongs to. There are *n*+1 = 6 intervals.

```
0 (-∞, 0]
1 (0, 1]
2 (1, 4]
3 (4, 10]
4 (10, 20]
5 (20, ∞)
```

Then *n* = 5 belongs to interval 3 which is `(4, 10]` and the result is 3.

### Explanation

```
I.~3!2+i.  Input: integer n
       i.  Range [0, n)
     2+    Add 2 to each
   3!      Combinations nCr with r = 3
I.~        Interval index of n
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 43 bytes

```
f=lambda n,i=0:n*6>-~i*i*(i+2)and-~f(n,i+1)
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [@FlipTack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60919/fliptack) and another 3 thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!

Comment: This gives `f(220)=11`, which should be `f(220)=10`.

Comment: Oh, I was using Python 2. This needs Python 3 to avoid floor division, though perhaps you can multiply on the other side instead to make it version-agnostic.

Comment: I think you can do  `and-~f(n,i+1)` for `and f(n,i+1)or i`. Strangely, it's usually shorter when you're counting up a variable recursively not to return it, but to instead increment the output recursively.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
+\⍣2∘⍳⍳⊢
```

My first time using APL, thanks to [H.PWiz](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/289893/h-pwiz) for [shortening it into a train](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52986161#52986161)

Essentially a port of [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108383/87923)

## Explanation

```apl
+\⍣2∘⍳⍳⊢
    ∘⍳    Numbers from 1 to input inclusive
+\        Cumulative reduce with addition, gets triangular numbers
  ⍣2      Repeat (does it again) to get the tetrahedral numbers
      ⍳⊢  Index of the input in that list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/tWMe9S42etQx41HvZhDqWvQ/DSjxqLfP6FFXM1BdcVEykCzJyCz@n6ZgZGQAAA)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is a valid solution as it fails for p = 221. It will only work for values of p that are exactly tetrahedral numbers

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
f=lambda x,i=1:f(x,i+1)if(i+3)*i+2<x/i*6else i
```

Comment: @FlipTack Argh! I'll fix it in a sec... nobody downvote, please.

Comment: You can prevent any downvoting by deleting your answer. You will then still be able to edit the answer and undelete it once it's fixed.

Comment: Also, this still doesn't do what the challenge asks. An input of `221` will crash it.

Comment: I've tested this on TIO and it crashes on all inputs. Is this my problem or is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: It worked for me. I'll test it again.

Comment: @JackBates Bother. I thought it only had to work for tetrahedron numbers. Fixed.

Comment: Why are people voting for this rubbish? Vote for @xnor's implementation instead; both of their methods are amazing.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 43 bytes

```
INPUT X
WHILE X>P
I=I+1
R=R+I
P=P+R
WEND?I
```

`I` is the day, `R` is the `i`th triangular number, and `P` is the `i`th tetrahedral number (number of presents).

I think a similar answer in another language, perhaps:
`x=>{while(x>p)p+=r+=++i;return i}` could be pretty good.

Comment: You want `?I` at the end, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
Floor@Root[x^3-x-6#+6,1]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>21</s> 23 bytes

```
floor.(**(1/3)).(*6.03)
```

Edit: As xnor pointed out, the original solution (`floor.(/0.82).(**0.4)`) didn't work between the days of christmas

Comment: This gives the wrong answer on many inputs, for example 221.

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 11 bytes

`#äµS¹µS>S1+`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=itr&src=I-S1U7m1Uz5TMSs=&in=MjIw)

## Explanation

```
#            ; read a number `n`  from standard input
 ä           ; duplicate that number
  µ          ; apply for all integers in the range [1,...,n]
   S         ; replace each element `k` of the range with the sum from 1 to `k`
    ¹        ; push all no-empty prefixes of that list
     µS      ; sum up the elements, this will give the list of the first `n` tetrahedral numbers
       >     ; vectorized comparison
        S    ; sum up, this will count the number of triangle numbers that are smaller than `n`
         1+  ; offset by one to get the right number
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 69 bytes

```
@set/an=d=t=0
:l
@set/at+=d+=n+=1
@if %t% lss %1 goto l
@echo %n%
```

Manually calculates tetrahedronal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Pyth 11 bytes**

```
/^Q.3335.55
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%5EQ.3335.55&input=286%0A%0A287&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A5%0A75%0A100%0A220%0A221%0A364&debug=0)

pretty much just translated [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108417/56201) into Pyth

Answer (score 0):

**R, 19 characters**

```
floor((n*6)^.33359)
```

based on xnor's answer in `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 19 bytes

This steals @xnor 's formula:

```
:?int((a*6)^.33359)
```

I tried dialing down the resolution to .3336 to save a byte, but that fails on the final testcase.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + bc, 44  bytes

```
bc -l <<< "f=e(.33359*l($1*6));scale=0;f/1"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
V≥¹∫∫ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@xR59JDOx91rAaihzsW////39wUAA) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFvuo6bG/2GPOpce2vmoYzUQPdyx@P///9GGOqY65qY6hgYGOkZGIGyoY2xmEgsA)

### Explanation

```
V≥¹∫∫ḣ
     ḣ range 1..n
   ∫∫  cumulative sum, twice
V      index of first element that is
 ≥¹    greater than or equal to the input
```